# Taylor series around a branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, multivalued-functions, branch-points

The function $w:=f(z)$ defined implicitly by $\Phi(w,z)=w^2-z^2-z^3=0 $ has two critical points, $z=0$ and $z=-1$. I thought both of them were branch points (and hence singularities) but I realized it's possible to expand (Taylor series) both branches about $z=0$:

$f_1(z)=\sqrt{z^2+z^3}=z+\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{1}{8}z^3$+...

$f_2(z)=-\sqrt{z^2+z^3}=-f_1(z)$

Thus is $f(z)$ analytic at $z=0$? If not, how is it possible to have a Taylor series around a singularity?

Comment: Yes $(1+z)^{1/2}$ is analytic at $z=0$. For algebraic curves, the branch points are of the form $(z-a)^b f(z), b\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f$ analytic around $z=a$. Indeed there is a 3rd branch point at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's analytic at $z=0$.  You can think of this as the product of $\sqrt{z^2}$ and $\sqrt{z+1}$.

The $\sqrt{z^2}$ part clearly has 2 branches ($\pm z$) which are analytic everywhere.

For the $\sqrt{z+1}$ part, you can choose a branch which is analytic at $z=0$ (there would only be a problem if you were centered at $z=-1$).

Comment: Thanks! Looking at it that way my question was quite obvious. I was confused because I always saw branch points as singularities of a multivalued function and its branches. Never thought in sqrt(z^2) as a counter-example. In this sense, I have another question: generically speaking, can the branches of a multivalued function yield to different behaviors with respect to a point z0? I mean, can I have Taylor series around z0 just in some of the branches?